# Crash when reading const* in c on ESP8266

Tags: c, arduino, esp8266, software-serial

I'm making a system that reads sensor value from Arduino Uno through SoftwareSerial and publishes it via MQTT. However, the problem I'm facing I think is more general, I must admit I am new to c.

I'm reading the data, and splitting it into two const* variables that are defined on the top of my program.

When I read back the saved "data" and "topic" variable that I have parsed from the Serial connection, I only get garbage output, and usually a crash that restarts the device.

It prints them successfully inside the read-from-serial function, but it can't be correctly read later. Can it have something to do with how the data is saved? Can I explicitly allocate some memory for the variables?

I'm using a ESP8266 (ESP07) chip with lowered baud rate and proper voltage supply. It seems to be running well and stable.

```
#include <StringSplitter.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <time.h>

//const char* ssid = "xxxx";
//const char* password =  "xxxx";
const char* ssid = "xxxx";
const char* password =  "xxxx";
const char* mqttServer = "xxxx;
const int mqttPort = xxxx;
const char* mqttUser = "xxxx";
const char* mqttPassword = "xxxx";
int timezone = 1;
int dst = 0;
```

The data is stored here:

```
char* data;
char* topic;
boolean newData = false;
boolean unpublishedData = false;

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(19200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
  configTime(timezone * 3600, dst * 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");


  client.setServer(mqttServer, mqttPort);
  client.setCallback(callback);

  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT...");

    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client", mqttUser, mqttPassword )) {

      Serial.println("connected");

    } else {

      Serial.print("failed with state ");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      delay(2000);

    }
    // wait and determine if we have a valid time from the network.
    time_t now = time(nullptr);
    Serial.print("Waiting for network time.");
    while (now <= 1500000000) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(300); // allow a few seconds to connect to network time.
      now = time(nullptr);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("");

  time_t now = time(nullptr);
  Serial.println(ctime(&now));

  String datatext = "val: ";
  String timetext = ", time: ";
  String dataToBeSent = "test";
  String timeToBeSent = ctime(&now);

  String publishString = datatext + dataToBeSent + timetext + timeToBeSent;
  Serial.println("Attempting to publish: " + publishString);
  client.publish("trykk/sensor0", (char*) publishString.c_str());
  client.subscribe("trykk/sensor0");

}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {

  Serial.print("Message arrived in topic: ");
  Serial.println(topic);

  Serial.print("Message:");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("-----------------------");

}

void loop() {
  client.loop();
  recvWithStartEndMarkers();
  showNewData();
  publishReceived();
}

void publishReceived() {
  if (unpublishedData) {
    Serial.println("Hello from inside the publisher loop!");
    time_t now = time(nullptr);
    char* timeNow = ctime(&now);
```

It fails here, reading the data:

```
    char publishText[30]; //TODO: make it JSON
    strcpy( publishText, data );
    strcat( publishText, " " );
    strcat( publishText, timeNow );

    Serial.print("publishText: ");
    Serial.println(publishText);
    Serial.print("topic: "); 
    Serial.println(topic);
    client.publish(topic, publishText);
    client.subscribe(topic);
    unpublishedData = false;
  } else if (!data) {
    Serial.println("No data saved to array.");
  } else if (!topic) {
    Serial.println("No topic saved to array.");
  }
}

void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
  int numChars = 32;
  char receivedChars[numChars];
  static boolean recvInProgress = false;
  static byte ndx = 0;
  char startMarker = '<';
  char endMarker = '>';
  char rc;

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.println("Hello from inside the receive loop!");
    delay(100);
    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
      rc = Serial.read();
      Serial.println("Reading from data line.");

      if (recvInProgress == true) {
        if (rc != endMarker) {
          receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
          ndx++;
          if (ndx >= numChars) {
            ndx = numChars - 1;
          }
        }
        else {
          Serial.println("Found the end marker.");
          receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
          recvInProgress = false;
          ndx = 0;
          newData = true;
          unpublishedData = true;
```

This part prints the values correctly back to me:

```
          //Split the string
          Serial.print("ESP debug: read: ");
          Serial.println(receivedChars);
          const char s[2] = ":";
          *data = strtok(receivedChars, s);
          Serial.print(data);
          Serial.print(" ");
          *topic = strtok(NULL, s);
          Serial.println(topic);
        }
      }

      else if (rc == startMarker) {
        recvInProgress = true;
        Serial.println("Found start marker");
      }
    }
  }
}

//This is gutted as it gave me problems reading the variables
void showNewData() {
  if (newData == true) {
    Serial.print("This just in ... ");
    Serial.print("Topic: ");
    Serial.print("stuff");
    Serial.print(", data: ");
    Serial.println("more stuff");
    newData = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are asking.  You precede the second (large) block of code with _"The data is stored here:"_ - what data, stored where?  Where does the `const*` in the title come in?  What symbol does it refer to - you have several `const*` and it is not clear that you are having any issue "reading" them?

Comment: You have a 'typo', just replace `*data = strtok(receivedChars, s);` by `data = strtok(receivedChars, s);` in `recvWithStartEndMarkers`, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing the assignment of `strtok`'s result to `data` as shown in bruno's answer there is another bug that can lead to a crash.

Your function `loop()` calls `recvWithStartEndMarkers()` first, then `publishReceived()`.

```
void loop() {
  client.loop();
  recvWithStartEndMarkers();
  showNewData();
  publishReceived();
}
```

In function `recvWithStartEndMarkers` you read some data into a local array `receivedChars`, feed this into `strtok` and write a pointer returned from `strtok` to a global variable `data`.

```
void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
  int numChars = 32;
  char receivedChars[numChars]; /* this is a local variable with automatic storage */
  /* ... */

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
      /* ... */
          receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
          ndx++;
          if (ndx >= numChars) {
            ndx = numChars - 1;
          }
          /* ... */
          receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
          /* Now there is a terminated string in the local variable */
          /* ... */

          //Split the string
          /* ... */
          const char s[2] = ":";
          data = strtok(receivedChars, s); /* strtok modifies the input in receivedChars and returns a pointer to parts of this array. */ 
          /* ... */
}
```

After leaving the function the memory that was `receivedChars` is no longer valid. This means `data` will point to this invalid memory on the stack.

Later you want to access the global variable `data` in a function `publishReceived()`. Accessing this memory is is unspecified behavior. You may still get the data, you may get something else or your program may crash.

```
void publishReceived() {
  /* ... */
    char publishText[30]; //TODO: make it JSON
    strcpy( publishText, data ); /* This will try to copy whatever is now in the memory that was part of receivedChars inside recvWithStartEndMarkers() but may now contain something else, e.g. local data of function publishReceived(). */
  /* ... */
```

To fix this you could use `strdup` in `recvWithStartEndMarkers()`:

```
data = strtok(receivedChars, s);
if(data != NULL) data = strdup(data);
```

Then you have to `free(data)` somewhere when you no longer need the data or before calling `recvWithStartEndMarkers()` again.

Or make `data` an array and use `strncpy` in `recvWithStartEndMarkers()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The out-of-scope reference was the source of my problems! The other mistake was just from an experiment, and I forgot to change it back, the compiler would have caught it.

Answer (score 5):

From your code :

> ```
> char* data;
> ...
> *data = strtok(receivedChars, s);
> ```

*strtok* return a `char*` but you do `*data = strtok(...)` while *data* is itself a (non initialized) `char *`, this is non consistent, and you have a first 'chance' to have a crash because you write at a random address.

If you do not have the crash and your program can continue *data* is not modified by itself and stay uninitialized.

In

> ```
> strcpy( publishText, data );
> ...
> Serial.print(data);
> ```

When you use *data* as a `char*` doing `Serial.print(data);` and `strcpy( publishText, data );` you read from a random (and certainly invalid) address, producing your crash.

To correct just replace `*data = strtok(receivedChars, s);` by `data = strtok(receivedChars, s);`